# How do you remove CKeditor's new image properties' photo upload, or browser server properties?

Tags: javascript, wysiwyg, ckeditor, fckeditor

I just upgraded my ckEditor, and it's added a few options I don't want right now.

Of them are to browse images from files rather than just include them as urls. How do I remove those options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your source HTML/JS file you'll have some code that replaces a `textarea` with the CKEditor. It reads something like:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1',
{
    … /* parameters */
    filebrowserUploadUrl : '/uploader/upload.php',
    … /* other parameters */
});
```

If you delete the `filebrowserUploadUrl` parameter (or empty the string assigned to it), the image upload tab will be gone.

Note that, apart from or instead of `filebrowserUploadUrl`, you can also have a parameter called `filebrowserImageUploadUrl`. In that case, you have to delete or empty this parameter as well.

See [File Browser (Uploader)](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/File_Browser_%28Uploader%29) for more details.

**Other solution**

You can also [customize every dialog](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Dialog_Customization):

> By listening to the `dialogDefinition`
>   event of CKEditor it's possible to
>   customize the dialogs **removing tabs** or
>   changing the default values.

So, if you want to remove the upload tab this way, just add the following code:

```
CKEDITOR.on( 'dialogDefinition', function( ev ) {
    // Take the dialog name and its definition from the event data
    var dialogName = ev.data.name;
    var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;

    if ( dialogName == 'image' ) {
        // Remove upload tab
        dialogDefinition.removeContents('Upload');
    }
});
```

Comment: I got that..ckeditor is a mess of a machine to figure out though. Have no idea where to put that info :D, let alone pinpoint it to remove what I need

Comment: I appreciate it, but I figured it all out already posted it above. Thanks so much Marcel

Comment: Also I want to know for that first part of your answer, that was located in a yaml file created by rails-ckeditor in my config/ . Just delete it, problem solved. Also if you ever run into this problem, make sure your `git rm` all your files from your remote. Anything hangers will ruin the project.

Answer (score 5):

Use the [removeDialogTabs](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.removeDialogTabs) parameter when you create the editor, for example, using the jQuery plugin:

```
$(selector).ckeditor({
    removeDialogTabs: 'link:target;link:upload;link:advanced;image:Link;image:advanced',
});
```

Comment: Suits me as I'm using it with jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

Just add this to your config.js . Good riddance.

```
CKEDITOR.on( 'dialogDefinition', function( ev ) {
   var dialogName = ev.data.name;
   var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;
   if ( dialogName == 'image' ) {
         dialogDefinition.removeContents( 'Link' );
         dialogDefinition.removeContents( 'advanced' );
         dialogDefinition.removeContents( 'Upload' );
   }
});
```

Comment: I need to make the url field disabled (but visible) is that possible?